# Java code working for Cassandra version 3.11 but not for 4.1 version

Tags: cassandra

I am working on parsing Commitlogs from CDC raw directory of Cassandra. Code is working with 3.11 version of Cassandra but not for 4.1 version. In 4.1 handler is not getting invoked. What could be the possible reason behind it? I tried to debug but couldn't find something which is useful

This is the code snippet I am trying:

```
private final CommitLogReader reader = new CommitLogReader();
private final CommitLogHandler handler = new CommitLogHandler();

public void read(Path absolutePath) throws IOException {
    // the last arg tolerateTruncation is false because 
    // Cassandra has a bug that can cause    infinite loop
    // when ignoring exception
    try {
        File cfp = new File(absolutePath.toFile());
        reader.readCommitLogSegment(handler, cfp, false);
        System.out.println("Done reading file :" +absolutePath.toString()); 
    } finally {
        if (!reader.getInvalidMutations().isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println(reader.getInvalidMutations());
        }
    }
}
```

In this case handler is of type CommitLogHandler which implements handleMutation(...) method of CommitLogReadHandler interface. handleMutation(...) is invoked by one of the other method from readCommitLogSegment(...) under some condition. And I think that condition is not hitting to call the handler. Can somebody please give me some pointers to it? What could be the possible reason behind it as it's working with old version but not latest version.